# Ruby string ignore last character

Tags: ruby, string

how to ignore last character inside string in ruby? if i have problem like this, example :

```
abc = "123456a"
```

how to get result like this :

```
abc = "123456"
```

i don't need last character inside the string, how to ignore it?

thanks before :)

Comment: Ignoring a character is easy, just don't reference it. :-) I understand what you are asking, but you should strive to be as concise and precise as possible. If you mean "delete", say "delete" (or "remove"). Here you might say, "How can I delete the last character of a string? For example, if `abc = "123456a"`, I want to change it to `abc = "123456"`." That's all you need. There's no need for your last sentence or to thank others in advance. (If you like, you can thank those who give good advice in comments.) Don't edit your question--this is just a suggestion for the future.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try:

```
abc.chop!
```

`chop` will delete the last character and `!` will change the content in place.

Comment: programmer ror juga ya mas @styd? orang jakarta?

Comment: bukan, mas. saya malah baru belajar ror. saya belajar ruby krna emang tertarik sama rubynya. saya kerja di jakarta tapi bukan di bidang TI. saya lagi iseng aja blajar ruby. hehe

Answer (score 1):

Try this solution:

```
my_string[0..-2]
```

Answer (score 0):

Negative indices index from the end, `-1` is the last character; so to get everything up to next to last character, you'd write

```
abc[0..-2]
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to make it.

```
abc[0..-2]

abc[0..(abc.length-2)]

abc.delete abc[-1]
```